# Changing (enlarging) the domain in a Quantified statement

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I would like to ask the following. If we have the proposition $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}(x^2>0)$$ and we wish to use as a domain the $$\mathbb{R}$$ instead. Is it correct that it will translate to: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}(x>0\land x^2>0)$$?

Similarly am I correct when from $$\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}(x^2=\sqrt2)$$ 
go to $$\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}(x>0\rightarrow x^2=\sqrt2)$$ ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  The first setup, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ (x^2 \gt 0)$, is a true statement but not as general as perhaps you'd like it to be.  The only real number whose square is *not* greater than zero is zero.  So you could state that in a variety of ways, some which would start by saying $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}(\ldots)$.

Comment: It is an exercise that I had to do and this is the answer I gave. And I am wondering is it true? (I do not care about whether the original proposition is true) I had to re-state it using R, and Z the second time, but should stay equivalent to the original.

Comment: Okay, then you used the wrong logical connective in the first case.  Should have been $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}( x \gt 0 \implies x^2 \gt 0)$, assuming that domain $\mathbb{R}^+$ in the original proposition referred to positive real numbers.  The second case, with the existential quantifier, is where you should use the logical connective "and" (but instead you used the "arrow").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have your implications and conjunctions swapped.

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} (x \gt 0 \land x^2 > 0) $$

Means "All real numbers are positive and have positive squares".

You're looking for

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} (x \gt 0 \implies x^2 > 0) $$

For the 2nd one, it's also the wrong way around.

$$ \exists x \in \mathbb{Z}(x \gt 0 \implies x^2 = \sqrt{2}) $$

Means "There is an integer which, if it is positive then its square is $ \sqrt{2} $".

i.e. "There is an integer which is either non-positive or its square is $\sqrt{2}$".

You're looking for

$$ \exists x \in \mathbb{Z}(x \gt 0 \land x^2 = \sqrt{2}) $$

Comment: Thank you, we were said in class exactly this when restricting the domain, but I got confused because now we had to enlarge it. Probably it follows the same rules...

Answer (score 0):

Two translatings are incorrect. First, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ (x^2 >0)$ is true, but $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} (x > 0 \wedge x^2 >0)$ is false. It might be corrected as $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}(x>0 \to x^2 > 0)$.
Second, $0,-1,-2,-3,\cdots$ show that $\exists x\in \mathbb{Z}(x>0\to x^2=\sqrt{2})$ is true, whereas there is no $x$ to show $\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}^+(x^2=\sqrt2)$.

For second example, $\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}(x^2=\sqrt2)$ means "There is an element $x$ such that $x\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ **and** $x^2=\sqrt{2}$". Then we can conclude cardboard_box's answer is correct.